# How to id the rows that are between a match of string in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I would like to be able to identify the fruits that are between the bananas with a unique value and have the last banana also marked with this unique value. Everything else, like before the first banana or after the last banana or if there are two, three bananas in a row - is not of my interest - they can have 0 as value or be deleted. Please refer to the desired output if I sound too confusing. I hope someone has an idea. I've been googling and stackoverflowing without any success. I hope it is not ridiculously easy that no one even asked before.

```
  fruits <- c("apples", "pears","bananas", "cherries")
  customer <- rep(c(1:10), each = 3)
  set.seed(1236)
  df_fruits <- data.frame(customer = sample(customer, 30, replace = T),
                    fruits = sample(fruits,30, replace = T, prob=c(0.29,0.60,0.5,0.1)))
  df_fruits <- distinct(df_fruits,.keep_all = T)
  df_fruits
```

Desired output

```
    customer   fruits section
1         8    pears       0
2         7 cherries       0
3         5  bananas       0
4         5    pears       1
5        10  bananas       1
6         9    pears       2
7        10    pears       2
8         1   apples       2
9         1    pears       2
10        4    pears       2
11        6    pears       2
12        6 cherries       2
13        4   apples       2
14        8   apples       2
15        2    pears       2
16        1  bananas       2
17        8  bananas       0
18        9  bananas       0
19        3  bananas       0
20        3    pears       3
21        2  bananas       3
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure I understood how you wanted to handle the bananas, but this might get you closer to what you need:

```
library(dplyr)

df_fruits %>%
  mutate(section = lag(cumsum(ifelse(fruits != lag(fruits) & fruits == "bananas", 1, 0)), default=0)) %>%
  filter (!(fruits == lag(fruits) & fruits == "bananas"))

customer   fruits section
1         8    pears       0
2         7 cherries       0
3         5  bananas       0
4         5    pears       1
5        10  bananas       1
6         9    pears       2
7        10    pears       2
8         1   apples       2
9         1    pears       2
10        4    pears       2
11        6    pears       2
12        6 cherries       2
13        4   apples       2
14        8   apples       2
15        2    pears       2
16        1  bananas       2
17        3    pears       3
18        2  bananas       3
```

Edit: I added filter to remove duplicate bananas which I just read was a consideration.

Comment: yes, your approach got me really close to what I was after. Thank you very much, I learned from you. If I don't want to preserve the duplicated fruits between the bananas then:
`df_fruits$fruits <- as.character(df_fruits$fruits)
df_fruits <- df_fruits %>% filter(fruits != lag(fruits, default="bananas")) ` and then `your code` got me the correct sections.  -All the best!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the updated version while I posted my comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your input data and desired output have different number of rows.
Using your desired output as input data, here's one way with `dplyr`. `output` is the calculated column which can be compared to your `section` column -

```
test <- df_fruits$fruits == "bananas"
df_fruits %>% 
  filter(!(test & lag(test))) %>% 
  mutate(
    output = cumsum(t <- fruits == "bananas") - t
  )

   customer   fruits section output
1         8    pears       0      0
2         7 cherries       0      0
3         5  bananas       0      0
4         5    pears       1      1
5        10  bananas       1      1
6         9    pears       2      2
7        10    pears       2      2
8         1   apples       2      2
9         1    pears       2      2
10        4    pears       2      2
11        6    pears       2      2
12        6 cherries       2      2
13        4   apples       2      2
14        8   apples       2      2
15        2    pears       2      2
16        1  bananas       2      2
17        3    pears       3      3
18        2  bananas       3      3
```

Comment: the different results might be due to the seed of the different r versions. Your method keeps the repetitions between the bananas - which indeed is what I intended.  I would need some time to understand and adopt your approach. :) Thank you very much! -All the best!